# C# Regex is matching only one of two groups

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list that contains with entries that will be in 1 of the 3 formats:

```
Test Section - Main Series - 
Test 2 Section - Test Section - Main Seris
Main Series -  -
```

I am try to use a RegEX to remove the training `-` from the lines. I came up with the following code to try and do it and it kind of works. It removed the double instance of dashes in the third format, leaves the second format alone, but ti does not remove the single instance of the dash in the first format.

```
        foreach (var item in menuItems)
        {
            item.NameWithParents = Regex.Replace(item.NameWithParents, @"(\s-\s\s-\s)|(\s-\s[^a-zA-Z])", "").ToString();
        }}
```

I had thought the first group would make it remove the double dash while the second group would remove the single dash but it is not. The output I get is:

```
Test Section - Main Series - 
Test 2 Section - Test Section - Main Seris
Main Series
```

Why is the single instance not being removed?

Comment: Your string `Test Section - Main Series - ` seems to end with just *one* white space, however your 2nd rx group `(\s-\s[^a-zA-Z])` expects two chars after the "-". So it doesn't match. A modification to `(\s-\s[^a-zA-Z]?)` could fix it.
In order to remove some char from the end of a string, using `RTrim` by the way is also fine and straight forward.

Comment: @lidqy Your modification removes all instances of ` - `. Also the second white space you are seeing (I don't see it) I think is from SO. When I look at the raw data in VS there is only a single space at the end.

Comment: What is the `[^a-zA-Z]` for? Why not just look for end of line with `$`?

Comment: @dc-ddfe Because I did not know about `$` which seems to be working now. thank you

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete I meant that you rx requests for two trailing spaces or chars (one by the \s the other by the [^A_Za-z]), not that your string had two trailing spaces.
Anyways, seems you've got it solved.